# Looping Through a ColdFusion Structure

Tags: arrays, loops, coldfusion, structure

Can someone help me loop through a structure.

```
<cfset resData2 = ConvertXmlToStruct(gatewayResponse.Filecontent, StructNew())>
<cfset resTran2 = 'resData2.Body.PosResponse.Ver1.0.Transaction.ReportBatchDetail.Details'> 
<cfloop index="idx2" from="1" to=#StructCount(resTran2)# step="1"> 
    <cfdump var="#resTran2#">
</cfloop>
```

Here is the structure:
[image]

Comment: Firstly, you should edit your question and remove the image of your code with the text instead.  If you're having trouble it's because you need to indent your code by 4 spaces and stackoverflow will display it as a code block.

Comment: Yes, please add your code in text (not an image) and also include the code within your loop showing how you are attempting to output/reference the object in each loop iteration. Also include any error(s) that your code is generating or the output and what you want. First hint is that you are setting `resTran` to a string, not the object, because you have it enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

A few issues with your code.  As @Miguel-F pointed out, your assignment to `restran2` should not be enclosed in quotes because you're making the assignment into a literal string.  Secondly, your result going into `resTran2` is an array of structs, so what you want to use for your upper loop limit is `ArrayLen()` and not `StructCount()`.  Lastly, because one of your keys `Ver1.0` contains a period in it, you will need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation to reference it.

```
<cfset resData2 = ConvertXmlToStruct(gatewayResponse.Filecontent, StructNew())>
<cfset resTran2 = resData2["Body"]["PosResponse"]["Ver1.0"]["Transaction"]["ReportBatchDetail"]["Details"]> 
<cfloop index="idx2" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(resTran2)#" step="1"> 
    <cfset batchID = resTran2["batchID"][idx2]>
    <cfset batchSeqNbr = resTran2["batchSeqNbr"][idx2]>
    ....
</cfloop>
```